# How to catch errors raised by AddressSanitizer in C++ libraries accessed via python extension

Tags: python, c++, distutils, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I have a python module that uses an external C++ library using a C++ extension build with distutils. When I compile the C++ library with the address sanitizer, -fsanitize option of GCC, I get a segfault when running unit tests. Now, initially I thought that it was because me using different compiler options for the two binaries, the C++ python extension and the library but now I am more and more convinced that this is because the address sanitizer found an error in the library and triggered a seg fault, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574091/addresssanitizer-crash-on-gcc-4-8). 
This is also supported by the fact that if I compile the C++ library without the address sanitizer, everything works fine. 
When I run unit tests, the program outputs very little information:

```
./run_unit_tests
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Even looking at the core dump I was able to find only a stack trace pointing to the C++ library but no mention of address sanitizer.

I have tried to use ASAN_OPTIONS to redirect the sanitizer output to a file but the sanitizer apparently does not pick up the options:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS=help=1 ./run_unit_tests
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What strategy should I take here to confirm that the seg fault coms from the sanitizer and possibly discover what kind of error it is?

Comment: You said you looked at the core dump but have you actually run it in a debugger to trace the problem?

Comment: I have tried but cannot really get a lot of information, I am not sure how I should analyze the core dump, should I specify the python executable or the C++ library when starting gdb?

Comment: @Perennialista One option is just running you app directly under GDB: `gdb -ex 'set environment ASAN_OPTIONS=...' -ex 'set environment LD_PRELOAD=...' --args /usr/bin/python ...`

Comment: Thank you @yugr, I have tried to run the python unit tests with GDB and seems like the segmentation fault happens when importing a C++ library. However, looking at the trace with GDB it does not seem like there is any error in the code, could the segfault be triggered from somewhere else? In the link you provided, under "AddressSanitizerAsDSO", I have found: `__asan_init is not called from preinit_array and so there is a risk that an instrumented code will get called before __asan_init (may cause SEGV at startup; still unlikely)`

Comment: "However, looking at the trace with GDB it does not seem like there is any error in the code" - I suggest you add backtrace to the question and also try setting `ASAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=2:debug=1`. Did you try exporting `LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: I have preloaded the correct ASAN library and now everything works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a few clarifications:

> this is because the address sanitizer found an error in the library and triggered a seg fault

When Asan detects an error, it will always emit a friendly error message. Segfault means that

- either instrumentation went wrong at some point
- or (much less likely) instrumented code inadverently triggered some already existing critical bug

> This is also supported by the fact that if I compile the C++ library with undefined behavior sanitizer, everything is working fine

UBSan is *much* simpler than ASan so in general you can not really share conclusions about them.

> I have tried to use ASAN_OPTIONS to redirect the sanitizer output to a file but the sanitizer apparently does not pick up the options:

The fact that `help=1` fails tells us that sanitized app segfaulted at early startup, before Asan was able to parse `ASAN_OPTIONS` and react appropriately. This usually happens when there is some basic issue in how Asan was enabled.

My guess is that you miss `LD_PRELOAD=path/to/libasan.so` environment setting which is required when when applying Asan to a single DSO instead of main application (as is the case with sanitized C/C++ plugins for interpreters, check [Asan FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)).

If this does not help, I suggest to provide more information (e.g. GCC version, symbolized stack at the point of segv).

Comment: I have modified the original post to specify that if I run the python unit tests with the C++ library compiled without address sanitizer, they pass but if I run them with the sanitized version of the library, I have a SEGFAULT.

Comment: I tried LD_PRELOAD but was apparently with the wrong library, I found the good one and now my python unit tests work! Thank you very much @yugr, I will accept your answer and try to improve my question with my most recent findings.

Comment: @Perennialista Happy hacking)